# Location of the Nginx default index.html file on MAC OS

Tags: macos, nginx

[image]

I have successfully installed nginx on my MAC with homebrew

```
brew install nginx
```

but i can't find from where is this default page called.

In nginx.conf under location says

```
root html;
```

and i can't find it. Please help.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Lewis4u's answer may be right! But I think we should have a clearer explanation

In nginx.conf file we see the root path is:

```
root   html;
```

The question is: Where is "html" relative path? 
This relative path is set at compile time. You can check the path by command

```
$>nginx -V
```

You will see "--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.0_1", this is the folder of nginx files. Now you should "cd" to this directory to see your "html" folder.

```
$> cd /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.0_1
$> ls -l html
```

Then you will see the "html" folder is a softlink to "/usr/local/var/www"

In conclusion, in my case, the "html" folder is "/usr/local/var/www". It may be different on your MAC. But hey, you got the method to find out. Right?!

Comment: Awesome answer! `-V` switch was very useful

Comment: is there anyway to change the prefix location?

Answer (score 25):

I found it finally on my own. It's in:

```
/usr/local/var/www/index.html
```

Comment: i can acces there only cli but not ui, how can move you on site dir

Comment: @matinict if you want to open the files in the finder (file manager), in the terminal type open .   (open followed by a dot)

Answer (score 9):

On later versions of brew, the location should be:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/www
```

Comment: Homebrew uses `/opt/homebrew/` on Apple Silicon/ARM. See https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that the nginx could be placed in homebrew directory if anyone had used `brew` to install.

On Mac OS Ventura, the executable was installed under

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx/<version>`

Example

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx/1.25.1._1`

conf files were placed under

`/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/`